# Mapping different ports to Java servlets

Tags: java, web-services, port, jax-rs

**Scenario**

I'm writing a small health check module (jar) that allows users to retrieve information via a JAX-RS REST service. Other applications that use JAX-RS can import this module and benefit from it. The module will use the JAX-RS implementation defined by the consuming application.

**Problem**

I want to be able to run the health check module on a different port. This will allow us to easily block access to it via the firewall. **Is it possible to have multiple ports that server HTTP requests? If so can I map these to different JAX-RS Services easily**

If I can't get around this I have been thinking about embedding a small http server into the health check module.

Comment: which server are you using ?

Comment: I am using TC Server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TC Server, but since it's based on Tomcat (AFAIK), you could try to configure an extra HTTP Conector for your custom port (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html). The problem then, is that your JAX-RS endpoints may allow incoming requests on both ports, so the problem remains the same. Then you could also add a Valve (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter) to filter clients based on their IP Address. All this is server configuration, not something based on your module, though.

But IMHO, the cleanest and safest solution would be to secure your JAX-RS Endpoints with authentication mechanisms (your data should be encrypted over an SSL connection anyway).